# Are there any Database solutions for Windows Runtime other than SQLite?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have around 1000 - 5000 records and want to save them in a database for a fast access.

I used SQLite in Windows Phone Runtime, but it is VERY slow, only 2-3 inserts in a second.

I'm wondering if there even exists any other database solutions faster than SQLite?

Comment: Do you need them to be in a relational db? How about just saving them in a file?

Comment: You should probably ask this on the software recommendations forum.

Comment: Yes I want it in a relational db for fast access. @yasen

Comment: Relational databases aren't intended for fast access, but for managing objects with relations. If yours don't have such or the relations are simple, it'll most likely be faster to use something else.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is - in short - no.

Microsoft has dropped the good old LINQ to SQL when they introduced Windows Store apps. That feature remains available only for Silverlight apps.

So far SQLite is the only way to go (imo). But I see lots of space for optimization here. If you only manage to insert 2-3 records in 1 second the bottleneck should not be SQLite. If have written apps that use SQLite and push 10-20 records into the DB within a heartbeat.

I don't know much about your code but judging from your speed issues you must have some really complicated mappings. If code optimization doesn't help you should try to loose some atomicity and combine some nested objects for the sake of a quicker query.

Speed could also depend on the wrapper you're using. SQlite-WinRT (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sqlite-Winrt/) is more plain SQL whereas SQLite-Net (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) maps your objects.

You could, of course, always write your own storage. Write a JSON file per entity to the roaming settings and you can save an object and all its nested entities in parallel. If it's only writing with not much reading in between you shouldn't run into concurrency issues. JSON.Net (http://james.newtonking.com/json) is quite fast and will serialize your objects in no time.

Last but no least: you could go for a solution that saves you some insert queries: Serialize your objects to json and put them in one single table. I'd benchmark that solution before actually using it as it's not very beautiful.

But: You might want to show us your code first before pulling out the big guns..

Comment: Thanks Fred for your informative answer. It's funny if Microsoft use SQLite in their official apps! I'm using SQLite-net. I'll try to optimize it more

Comment: Also note that per the official SQLite docs, if you're inserting several things at once you should use an explicit transaction (otherwise you have overhead of many implicit transactions). Even so, you should get way more than 2-3 so I agree something else is wrong (OR you're using a very slow SD card)