# sql engine for local datastore in windows app

Tags: c#, mongodb, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I would write an application where I have local database which has ~650K rows. This database will have ~3 tables and my app will use in 99% queries about selection. What kind of db is better? Sqlite or MongoDb? The application will be for windows 8.1/windows phone. Generally for .NET.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287966/reasons-for-and-against-moving-from-sql-server-to-mongodb

Comment: It depends on how you intend to distribute your app. SQLite is made to be embedded into an application while MongoDB is a separate service/process on the computer. You also mention Windows Phone which I doubt you will be able to run MongoDB on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option for you in a universal app running with Windows Runtime is SQLite. There are noSQL databases that run on Silverlight but this does not apply for universal apps.

You can either install the extension via Visual Studio or download it on the SQLite website:

http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

There are a few wrappers for SQLite on Windows Phone:

- SQLite-net: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net
- SQLite-WinRT: https://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/

I'd suggest you import both of these and see which delivers the best performance for you.

SQLite-net is certainly the best option if you're working with object instances and want to query them in a LINQ manner.

SQLite-WinRT offers a more pure approach that works with raw SQL queries which might be faster (I haven't benchmarked it yet).

P.S.: Without knowing about your data structure it's almost impossible to tell which kind of DB is better.

These are also answers you can refer to:

[Are there any Database solutions for Windows Runtime other than SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460566/are-there-any-database-solutions-for-windows-runtime-other-than-sqlite/27465205#27465205)

[Sqlite data reader for Windows phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743397/sqlite-data-reader-for-windows-phone-8-1/27754838#27754838)

Comment: I co-wrote SQLite-WinRT with Andy. It is a *very* thin C++ /CX wrapper that talks directly to SQLite's C API. There are no frills :-) but if you are happy writing `SELECT` statements then it might suffice. If you are going to do any non-trivial number of `INSERT`s, you should read [this page from SQLite's manual](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19). The API does force everything to be a "roundtrip" Async call, which can be a pain if you're looping through a lot of rows. I don't know if SQLite-net treats that better.